# Importing nulls from Excel to Access yields an import error

Tags: excel, import, null

I am trying to import a table from Excel 2010 (.xlsx file) to Access 2010. There are 3 columns which I have set to double; they contain some blank cells in Excel (filtering shows they are blank, not space characters or else). I would have expected them to be imported as nulls into Access; they are, but Access creates an import error for every blank cell.

How can I fix this? In this specific case I have manually verified that the columns only contain numbers and nulls, but, in general, I don't want import error for nulls, as it would make it confusing to distinguish between an import error caused by a null and one caused by, say, trying to import a string into a column set as double.

Thanks!

Comment: Are the 'blanks' actually zero-length strings returned by formulas (e.g. "")? If so, you need to perform a `.Value = .Value` to get rid of the formulas then a sweep through the columns with Text-to-Columns, Fixed width to convert the zero-length strings to truly blank cells.

Comment: No, there are no formulae at all. =and(cell="") returns TRUE, but this doesn't mean much because it's true of every unused cell, jsut like =and(cell=0). Eg if you create a new spreadhseet and type =and(b10="") and =and(b10=0) they will both return TRUE. This is yet another proof that Excel is a very poor software and doesn't have the concept of NULL, but that's another story.